# React + Typescript: Is depending on type inferencing several levels deep frowned upon?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an existing React + Javascript project that I am migrating to Typescript.

My existing code has a really nice unidirectional flow that I'd like to preserve while adding types. It currently flows like this:

```
1. Component: FoobarListComponent -> useQueryFetchFoobars()

2. Hook: useQueryFetchFoobars() -> FoobarApi.list()

3. API: FoobarApi.list() -> axios.get("/api/v1/foobars")
```

Because it is in JS, it is often unclear what the response types of the API endpoints are. In the example above, there isn't typing so the developer has no clue what a `foobar` object looks like. This is where I'd like to utilize Typescript.

I would like to type all of my API response payloads. However, I would prefer that only the API level (#3 in the sequence above ^) knows about it because currently there is a clear separation between `Components -> Hooks -> APIs`. If I do it on another level, it feels a bit wrong... Also I would prefer not to export the types because currently my components never import from the API level directly.

This is an example of what I would prefer not to do:

```
import React from "react";
import useQueryFoobars from "hooks/useQueryFoobars";
import { FoobarListResponseType } from "apis/foobar";

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { data } = useQueryFoobar<FoobarListResponseType | null>();

  ...
}
```

The backend is written poorly, so I can't expect all the objects to look the same when accessing the same resource. What I mean by this is sometimes the detail API and the list APIs will return different shaped objects, like so:

```
GET /api/v1/foobars
[
  { id: "f1", name: "Baz" },
  { id: "f2", name: "Lorem" },
]

GET /api/v1/foobar/f1
{ id: "f1", name: "Baz", email: "something@yahoo.com , address: "..." },
```

Therefore I would like to have the flexibility of typing each endpoint individually.

One solution I was thinking of was to export the types inside the API files. However, wouldn't that mean Typescript would have to infer my type from 2 levels down? `API -> Hook -> Component?`

1. Is that acceptable in the TS world?
2. Is my assumption correct that TS will be able to infer the type?

Or is it expected to explicitly set the types at each level? Please let me know if my thinking is off, this is my first time using TS.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you afraid of importing types? They are virtually non-existent at runtime, and add nothing to the resulting bundle size.

In any case, typescript has pretty good type inference without requiring explicit typing, but this also depends on the way you have configured your `tsconfig.json`.

Therefore, to some degree it is possible to only have types in the API level, while still maintaining that strong typing in the modules that make use of the API. For the most part, your mileage will depend on your IDE, and whether or not you have `allowJs` enabled in the tsconfig (*if you are still mixing typescript with javascript*).

For your example, if you just declare `FoobarApi.list()` as:

```
namespace FoobarApi {
  export const list = () => axios.get<FoobarListResponseType>("/api/v1/foobars");
}

export default FoobarApi;
```

Then this is all the type information typescript needs to be able to infer the type of the `data` property for the response.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! To answer your question: I am hesitant to import types because 1) it feels like I will start mixing types into files that were once solely focused on one thing 2) I am not sure where to store my types. `src/types/api`?

Comment: @bigpotato I usually store them inside a file called `types.ts` within the folder where they are used. Then I import types using `import type {TypeA, TypeB, etc...} from module/types`. Anyways I understand the hesitence, but if you use the [`import type`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export) syntax, I think that can also aid to make it clear that those imports are for type information